# Sort array with 2 sort descriptors

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsdate

I have an array of `NSDictionary` objects, each object have an `EventDate` and `SecurityLevel`. I want to sort them first by dates and then by security levels. How can I do that?

```
Obj1: SecurityLevel: 5, Date: 20/05/2015 22:03
Obj2: SecurityLevel: 5, Date: 05/03/2015 05:28
Obj3: SecurityLevel: 4, Date: 14/04/2015 11:01
Obj4: SecurityLevel: 4, Date: 07/08/2015 09:31
Obj6: SecurityLevel: 3, Date: 24/04/2015 21:06
Obj5: SecurityLevel: 3, Date: 29/01/2016 22:38
Obj7: SecurityLevel: 2, Date: 02/06/2015 20:49
Obj8: SecurityLevel: 2, Date: 13/07/2015 17:46
Obj9: SecurityLevel: 1, Date: 19/08/2015 07:57
```

They should be sorted like that:

```
Obj1: SecurityLevel: 5, Date: 20/05/2015 22:03
Obj2: SecurityLevel: 5, Date: 05/03/2015 05:28
Obj4: SecurityLevel: 4, Date: 07/08/2015 09:31
Obj3: SecurityLevel: 4, Date: 14/04/2015 11:01
Obj5: SecurityLevel: 3, Date: 29/01/2016 22:38
Obj6: SecurityLevel: 3, Date: 24/04/2015 21:06
Obj8: SecurityLevel: 2, Date: 13/07/2015 17:46
Obj7: SecurityLevel: 2, Date: 02/06/2015 20:49
Obj9: SecurityLevel: 1, Date: 19/08/2015 07:57
```

I did something like that, but it's not working as expected:

```
- (NSArray*)sortEventsByDateAndSecurity:(NSArray*)toSort
{
    NSSortDescriptor *securityDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"SeverityLevel" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[securityDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedSecurity = [toSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSArray *reverseOrderUsingComparator = [sortedSecurity sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

        NSDictionary *dictObject1 = (NSDictionary*)obj1;
        NSDictionary *dictObject2 = (NSDictionary*)obj2;

        NSDate *obj1Date = [Utils stringToDate:[dictObject1 valueForKey:@"EventDate"] format:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSDate *obj2Date = [Utils stringToDate:[dictObject2 valueForKey:@"EventDate"] format:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

        return [obj1Date compare:obj2Date];
    }];

    return reverseOrderUsingComparator;
}
```

Comment: Why are you holding the dates as strings?  It's much more efficient (and useful) to convert them to `NSDate` objects as soon as they are imported into the app.

Comment: OK, let's say I converted them to NSDate objects, how to sort the objects as I want?

Comment: Dunno.  Just a comment about using the correct type to represent your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply call `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` with array of 2 descriptors instead of 1:

```
- (NSArray*)sortEventsByDateAndSecurity:(NSArray*)toSort
{
    NSSortDescriptor *securityDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"SeverityLevel" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *eventDateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"EventDate" ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
        NSDate *obj1Date = [Utils stringToDate:obj1 format:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSDate *obj2Date = [Utils stringToDate:obj2 format:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
        return [obj1Date compare:obj2Date];
    }];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[securityDescriptor, eventDateDescriptor];
    return [toSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

In this case, second sort descriptor will be applied only to objects, that are equal in terms of first sort descriptor. For your case that means, that objects with same `SecurityLevel` will be sorted by `EventDate`.